# Playing Master of Evolution without a valid card to evolve to

Tags: hearthstone

If I play Master of Evolution which transforms a friendly minion to a random one that costs 1 more, but there isn't a valid minion in the game that costs that much, what will happen to my minion?

For example, if I use the Battlecry of this minion on a minion with a cost of 10, but there is no valid minion in the game with a mana cost of 11, what happens?

[image: master of Evolution card]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If there is no valid target, nothing will happen:

[image: Twitter image]
[(Link)](https://twitter.com/playhearthstone/status/716000263149060098)

Answer (score 4):

The battlecry will do nothing if a valid minion does not exist with the appropriate mana cost.

Comment: Do you have proof or a source for your answer?

Comment: [Noted in comments on HearthHead](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=39008/master-of-evolution), with one mentioning a blue tweet about it, but, link not provided. The interaction is definitely not difficult to test out on your own.

Comment: You should probably include that in your answer